# Repaint TextFile in JPanel

Tags: java

I quite new in java and I encounter a problem with repaint a TextFile in my JPanel, this is code:

```
JPanel paneldol = new JPanel();

        paneldol.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Oblicz pole i obwód")
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                paneldol.repaint();
                paneldol.revalidate();

            }
        }
        ));
        paneldol.add(new TextField(model.getPole(), 10));
        paneldol.add(new TextField(model.getObwod(), 10));
        this.add(paneldol, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

As you see TextField have metod that generate string, so when i click in button I want to repain panel to have new value in my Textfield, Is this possibly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so when i click in button I want to repain panel to have new value in my Textfield, Is this possibly?"`

If all you want to do is to change the text in text field on button push, then you should give your class a JTextField variable (or multiple JTextField variables), assign a JTextField object to the variable, and this to the GUI. Then when within your button's listener, simply set the text of the JTextField via its `setText(...)` method. There's no need to call `repaint()` or `revalidate()` as they will do nothing useful in this situation.

Also don't mix AWT with Swing components. Use JTextFields not TextFields.